# Integrate Angular JS in Symfony2

Tags: angularjs, symfony

i try to integrate angularJS into Symfony2 but I am having some difficulty
Below you will find the code of the page base.html.twig and code of my page app.js

```
<html lang="fr" ng-app="routeApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            Accueil !
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    {% block stylesheets %} 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/bootstrap/dist/css/base-admin.css') }}" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/angular/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/angular/angular-route.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/components/angular/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ardbackend/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>
    <nav>
        <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-primary">Page d'accueil</a>
        <a href="#/" class="btn btn-success">Page de contact</a>
    </nav>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my app.js

```
'use strict';


/**
 * Déclaration de l'application routeApp
 */
var routeApp = angular.module('routeApp', [
    // Dépendances du "module"
    'ngRoute'
]);

/**
 * Configuration du module principal : routeApp
 */
routeAp

p.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) { 

    // Système de routage
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('login'),
        controller: SecurityController
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('pour_test'),
        controller: DefaultController
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

I did not understand, what's missing in my code to make it work
any help please ?

Comment: Could you please add some information about ... what exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors/exceptions ?

Comment: I have no mistakes, I have the impression that nothing happens

Comment: normally what are the steps to set up AngularJS with Symfony2

Comment: You can easily find numerous tutorials on how to integrate AngularJS with symfony. stackoverflow is **not** the platform for that kind of "getting started" guides. Ask a concrete question and you will very likely get help ... but if you're looking for a generic tutorial, please use a search engine. If you have a concrete problem with the integration, come back here.

Comment: AFAIK, you would use  AngularJS templating to avoid server side templating (for which data binding front end will more more difficult and will result in code duplication... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366386/frontend-vs-backend-template-rendering/). So, Twig here is useless, always try to return JSON. I hope it helps future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change start and ending symbols in angular , because as I understood it conflicts with same notation

```
   customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
  });;
```

Comment: I not use parameters currently twig in my pages I want to have just the two buttons that allows me to see the two roads with angular
but otherwise we can not use this syntax? {% verbatim %}{{yourName}}{% endverbatim %}

Comment: you also can use the ng-bind on some element eg <span ng-bind="foo"></span>

Comment: when defining the controller. is the symfony or angular controller ?

Comment: I am very far for it to work, I think I have something misconfigured

Comment: you have any other questions ?

Comment: I followed this course
http://www.tutoriel-angularjs.fr/tutoriel/2-utilisation-complete-d-angularjs/1-le-routage
but when I tried to integrate in Symfony2 it did not work, I am lost on how I can find out the source of the problem
in the console I get this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=routeApp&p1=Error%3…%2Fbundles%2Fardbackend%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A232)